# How to put text between a number? (C)

Tags: c

How do I insert text between a variable? Example: the interger is a = 1514 and I want to print it as 15:14. What should I do?

I'm really sorry people, I've been thinking a lot about how would I ask this question and this was the only thing that came to my mind... Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: `printf("%02d:%02d", a/100, a%100)`

Answer (score 0):

iBug's comment will give you EXACTLY what you asked for above, but otherwise you can use sprintf to store the integer in a string and then manipulate it however you wish from there.  Like:

```
sprintf(&number_string, "%d", int_variable);
```

and then if you want to always put text in the middle, something like:

```
int num_len = strlen(number_string);
int midpoint = len / 2;
char middle_text[6] = ":foo:";
int mid_text_len = strlen(middle_text);

// allocate space for new string
char *new_string = malloc(len + mid_text_len + 1);

// copy up to the midpoint into the new string
strncpy(new_string, number_string, midpoint);

// then concatenate whatever you want to put in the middle
strcat(new_string, middle_text);

// then concatenate the rest of number_string onto the end
strcat(new_string, number_string+midpoint, num_len-midpoint);

// and make sure it's null terminated.
new_string[len+mid_text_length] = '\0';
```

Caveat: I didn't test this code, so it might not work exactly as written...but you get the idea.